# Segmentation fault on 2D array

Tags: segmentation-fault, fortran

I have the code below. When I uncomment `temperature(i,j) = anode_temperature`, I SegFault.

```
forall(i=0:Cells(1), j=0:Cells(2), j >= nint(upperBoundary(i * delta(1)) / delta(2)))
    phi(i,j) = Anode_Voltage
!   temperature(i,j) = anode_temperature
end forall
```

However, I can access every element using the code below.

```
do i = 0,Cells(1)
    do j = 0,Cells(2)
        temperature(i,j) = anode_temperature
        write(*,*) i,j,temperature(i,j)
    enddo
enddo
```

Here is a self-contained program. Since someone mentioned they used ifort, I am using ifort 14.

```
program Main
implicit none

REAL, PARAMETER :: Pi = 3.14159265359
integer,parameter :: ND = 2

real, parameter :: RL = 1.0E-6  !Boundary radius
real, parameter :: HN = 5.0E-6  !Length of included needle
real, parameter :: HL = 2.0E-6  !Tip height

real, parameter :: LTT = 3E-6   !Tip-to-tip distance

real, parameter :: RU = 0.5E-6  !Boundary radius
real, parameter :: HU = 1.5E-6  !feature height

real, parameter :: zLen = HN + HL + LTT + HU

real,parameter,dimension(ND) :: Length = (/ 20E-6, zLen /)          !computational domain size (r,z)

! Grid Spacing
real, parameter, dimension(ND) :: delta = (/ 1.0E-8 , 1.0E-8 /)
integer, PARAMETER, dimension(ND) :: cells = Length / delta

real,parameter :: VApplied = -150

REAL, PARAMETER :: cathode_temperature = 1473.14        !Cathode Temperature [K]
REAL, parameter :: anode_temperature = 973.14           !Anode Temperature [K]
real :: Cathode_Voltage, Anode_Voltage

REAL, dimension(0:cells(1), 0:cells(2)) :: phi
REAL, dimension(0:cells(1), 0:cells(2)) :: temperature              !grid-wise gas temperature

integer:: i,j

phi = 0.0
temperature = 0.0

    Cathode_Voltage = VApplied
    Anode_Voltage = 0

forall(i=0:Cells(1), j=0:Cells(2), j <= nint(lowerBoundary(i * delta(1)) / delta(2)))
    phi(i,j) = Cathode_Voltage
    temperature(i,j) = cathode_temperature
end forall

forall(i=0:Cells(1), j=0:Cells(2), j >= nint(upperBoundary(i * delta(1)) / delta(2)))
    phi(i,j) = Anode_Voltage
    temperature(i,j) = anode_temperature
end forall

!forall(i=0:Cells(1), j=0:Cells(2), (j > nint(lowerBoundary(i * delta(1)) / delta(2))) .and. (j < nint(upperBoundary(i * delta(1)) / delta(2))))
!   phi(i,j) = Cathode_Voltage + (Anode_Voltage - Cathode_Voltage) * ((delta(2) * j - lowerBoundary(i * delta(1)) ) / ( upperBoundary(i * delta(1)) - lowerBoundary(i * delta(1)) ))
!   temperature(i,j) = cathode_temperature + (anode_temperature - cathode_temperature) * ((delta(2) * j - lowerBoundary(i * delta(1)) ) / ( upperBoundary(i * delta(1)) - lowerBoundary(i * delta(1)) ))
!end forall

contains
    pure function LowerRegion(r) result(k)

    implicit none
        real,intent(in) :: r
        integer :: k

        if (r < 0) then
            k = 0
        elseif (r < RL) then
            k = 1
        elseif (r >= RL) then
            k = 2
        elseif (r > R) then
            k = 3
        endif
    end function LowerRegion

    pure function UpperRegion(r) result(k)

    implicit none
        real,intent(in) :: r
        integer :: k

        if (r < 0) then
            k = 0
        elseif (r < RU) then
            k = 1
        elseif (r >= RU) then
            k = 2
        elseif (r > R) then
            k = 3
        endif
    end function UpperRegion


!!!!!!!!!!!! Define geometry for regions radially !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    pure function lowerBoundary(r) result(z)

    implicit none
        real,intent(in) :: r
        real :: z

        if (LowerRegion(r) == 1) then
            z = HN + HL * (1.0 - (r / RL))
        elseif (LowerRegion(r) == 2) then
            z = 0.0
        endif
    !end function lowerBoundary_Scalar
    end function lowerBoundary

    pure function upperBoundary(r) result(z)

    implicit none
        real,intent(in) :: r
        real :: z

        if (UpperRegion(r) == 1) then
            z = zLen - HU * (1.0 - (r / RU))
        elseif (UpperRegion(r) == 2) then
            z = zLen
        end if
    end function upperBoundary

end program Main
```

Comment: Off by one? Try `i=0:Cells(1)-1, j=0:Cells(2)-1`

Comment: I'm declaring from 0, `REAL, dimension(0:cells(1), 0:cells(2)) :: temperature`

Comment: And the `do` loop works.

Comment: It'd be best for us to see a complete example capable of reproducing the error. I'm particularly interested in the values and declaration of `Cells`, `delta`, and `upperBoundary`. Have you tried compiling with bounds checking?

Comment: I don't know if `:` is inclusive or not.

Comment: Can't reproduce with `forall(i=0:Cells(1), j=0:Cells(2), j >= i) temperature(i,j) = anode_temperature` and gfortran 5.

Comment: Cannot reproduce with ifort 16.  Can you try with a newer version of ifort?

Comment: I realized it doesn't seg faults if I compile using the command `ifort main.f90 -o a -mkl -warn noalign -autodouble -check bounds -check pointers -check uninit -heap-arrays
` but does seg fault if I compile using `ifort main.f90 -o a -g -CB -CU -debug -traceback -check bounds -mkl -warn noalign -autodouble -check bounds -check pointers -check uninit -heap-arrays`

Comment: Might be a compiler bug, try to narrow down the offending compiler flag and consider reporting to intel.

Comment: I rechecked with your compiler flags and still can't reproduce on ifort 16.  I second the advice above to narrow down the flag that produces the behavior and post on intel's dev forum (unless you have premier support, then use that channel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was suggested by @haraldkl, there was a compiler bug. The combination of the `forall` loops and the `-g` compiler flag (or more specifically the `-O0` flag this automatically causes). This is the post I made on the Intel forum.

https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-fortran-compiler-for-linux-and-mac-os-x/topic/593599